# UndecidableInstances and newtypes

Tags: haskell

I have an `UndecidableInstances` problem that I haven't been able to figure out how to avoid using `newtype`. Here's what I had originally:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

class Record r where
  key :: r -> String

class (Record r) => SizedRecord r where
  size :: r -> Int

class Database d where
  type DBRecord d

class (Record a) => Agent a where
  agentId :: a -> String
  agentId = key

class (Database (UAgentDB u), Agent (UAgent u), Record (UAgent u))
      => Universe u where
  type UAgent u
  type UAgentDB u
  -- plus other stuff

data SimpleUniverse d = SimpleUniverse
  {
    suDB :: d
    -- plus other stuff
  } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance (Record (DBRecord d)) => Universe (SimpleUniverse d) where -- line 28
  type UAgent (SimpleUniverse d) = DBRecord d
  type UAgentDB (SimpleUniverse d) = d
  -- plus other stuff
```

The message I get is

```
amy9.hs:28:10:
    Constraint is no smaller than the instance head
      in the constraint: Record (DBRecord d)
    (Use -XUndecidableInstances to permit this)
    In the instance declaration for `Universe (SimpleUniverse d)'
```

I want to avoid `UndecidableInstances` because this code is going to be in a reusable library, so I try declaring a `newtype`:

```
newtype SimpleUniverse2 u = SimpleUniverse2 { fromAdditiveGroup :: u }

instance (Record (DBRecord u)) => Universe (SimpleUniverse2 u) where
  type UAgent (SimpleUniverse2 u) = DBRecord u
  type UAgentDB (SimpleUniverse2 u) = u
  -- plus other stuff
```

But I get the same error. I've read answers to other questions on `UndecidableInstances`, but I haven't been able to solve this.

Comment: Why exactly do you not want `UndecidableInstances`? There's not much bad about that one.

Comment: If it's OK to use here, that's grand. I only thought I should avoid it because of posts like this: https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2008/04/08/stop-using-undecidable-instances/

Comment: It's totally ok here, as long as you won't start defining `Record` instances based on some `Universe`.

Answer (score 1):

As a horrible kludge, double-wrapping and using `FlexibleInstances` seem to do the trick:

```
import Control.Monad.Identity    

instance (Database u, Agent (DBRecord u), Record (DBRecord u)) =>
         Universe (Identity (Identity u)) where
  type UAgent (Identity (Identity u)) = DBRecord u
  type UAgentDB (Identity (Identity u)) = u
```